# Tableview showing incorrect data while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a tableview and its custom tableviewcell looks like so...

[Tableviewcell shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2uzN.png)

Now the checkbox named `option` is set up using delegates and it is accessed in the viewcontroller like so...

```
func optionBtnTapped(cell: UpdatingListTableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = standardsProceduresView.tableview?.indexPath(for: cell) {

        cell.optionBtn.isSelected = !cell.optionBtn.isSelected
        if(cell.optionBtn.isSelected)
        {

            //VALUE SET SINCE CHECKBOX ENABLED
            ... ... ...

            let image = UIImage(named: "checkbox.png") as UIImage?
            cell.optionBtn.setImage(image, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
        else
        {
            let image = UIImage(named: "square.png") as UIImage?
            cell.optionBtn.setImage(image, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
     }
   }
```

Similarely the `done` checkbox and `planned` checkbox (as shown in the image above) is also set up.

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks like so...

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UpdatingListTableViewCell = self.standardsProceduresView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: "cellClass") as! UpdatingListTableViewCell

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.delegate = self

    //Setting up values from an array into the label named 'Risk assessment done' in the tableviewcell
    resolutionDic = resolutionDetailsArray[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary
    cell.stdProcedLbl.text = "\(resolutionDic["Resolution"]!)"

    return cell

}
```

Now the issue is if I select the checkbox at the first cell and then scroll down, some other checkboxes at some different cells is also appearing selected. The same happens with done and planned checkboxes also. The same thing happens for the textfield called `whoTextfield`(shown in the image.) also. If I type in something there at the first cell and scroll down, the text appears in cells I didn't type the text into...

Referred other SO posts with similar issue. But couldn't find a solution for this issue...

EDIT: This is my code for tableviewcell..

```
class UpdatingListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var optionBtn: RoundButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var plannedBtn: RoundButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var doneBtn: RoundButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var whoTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var stdProcedLbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!
    var delegate: updatingDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        plannedBtn.isEnabled = false
        doneBtn.isEnabled = false
        whoTextField.delegate = self
        whoTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func optionBtnTapped(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        if let _ = delegate {
            delegate?.optionBtnTapped(cell: self)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func plannedBtnTapped(_ sender: RoundButton) {
       if let _ = delegate {
            delegate?.plannedBtnTapped(cell: self)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func doneBtnTapped(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        if let _ = delegate {
            delegate?.doneBtnTapped(cell: self)
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UITableViewCell`s get reused, if you want to set the correct data in a cell every time you scroll, you have to populate the entire cell data for the corresponding cell in the `cellForRow` method because it will be called every time you scroll to a new cell.

Comment: yes. ...But I'm not sure how I can do it in my case...

Comment: If the cell's state change store it and populate the data accordingly. In your case, you seem to be changing the image of a cell that is selected, set the image again when that indexPath is called.

Comment: But I can select multiple cells also...if I select two cells, how can I compare against both these indexes while scrolling...?

Answer (score 0):

Your cells are being reused so when a checkbox is selected and you don't reset this checkbox later, its UI state is reused for a different index path. You could reset your checkbox in the cell's `prepareForReuse` function or make sure to assign the correct checkbox status in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the cell's `optionBtn.isSelected = false` and `optionBtn.setImage(nil, for: .normal)` properties in `prepareForReuse()`, as follows (inside your `UITableViewCell` subclass):

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    optionBtn.isSelected = false
    optionBtn.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: @user987654, ahh yea- you also need to reset `optionBtn.image` to nil on reuse, see update

Comment: Now the cells I didn't select are not showing selected, but the one selected is also resetting @10623169

Answer (score 0):

As stated by other answers the problem is related with the cell being reused. To solve your problem you need to store the selection status of each index, this can be done with an array or custom object. In this example a simple list `isSelectedList` will be used.

```
var isSelectedList: [Int: Bool] = [:]
```

Here the `optionBtnTapped` is used to save the selection status when it changes.

```
func optionBtnTapped(cell: UpdatingListTableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = standardsProceduresView.tableview?.indexPath(for: cell) {

        cell.optionBtn.isSelected = !cell.optionBtn.isSelected

        // save the new isSelected value, you will need it on the tableView cellForRowAt method call
        isSelectedList[indexPath.row] = cell.optionBtn.isSelected

        if(cell.optionBtn.isSelected)
        {

            //VALUE SET SINCE CHECKBOX ENABLED
            ... ... ...

            let image = UIImage(named: "checkbox.png") as UIImage?
            cell.optionBtn.setImage(image, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
        else
        {
            let image = UIImage(named: "square.png") as UIImage?
            cell.optionBtn.setImage(image, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
     }
}
```

The final step is to always update the cell with the last saved selection status.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UpdatingListTableViewCell = self.standardsProceduresView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: "cellClass") as! UpdatingListTableViewCell

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.delegate = self


    // Here you customize the cell according to the isSelected value, like you do on the optionBtnTapped method. You should also respect the DRY pattern 
    if isSelectedList[indexPath.row] == true {
        cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)
    } else {
        cell.setSelected(false, animated: false)
    }



    //Setting up values from an array into the label named 'Risk assessment done' in the tableviewcell
    resolutionDic = resolutionDetailsArray[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary
    cell.stdProcedLbl.text = "\(resolutionDic["Resolution"]!)"

    return cell

}
```

Comment: ok @Claudio..So for the other checkboxes and textfield also, I'll have to repeat the same thing..?

Comment: Yes. You need to have all the data stored, and every time the cellForRowAt is called you must update all the checkboxes and textfields otherwise there will inconsistencies on the presented cells.

Comment: its not working @Claudio...the checkboxes are again repeating...

Comment: Please explain yourself better, what do you mean by repeating?

Comment: ok @Claudio. I had selected the checkbox at the first cell. But when I scrolled down the checkboxes at other cells were also showing selected.

Comment: That's probably because you are not resetting the cell, on the tableView cellForRowAt make sure you are disabling the select box

Comment: Can you maybe just show how I can do that @Claudio..?

Comment: Have edited the question with the code for tableviewcell.@Claudio

Comment: I’ve updated my answer, you’ll have to add the logic on the setSelected method to represent the changes